# How to Copy column data from one table to another by matching Column names? in SQL or Power Query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, powerquery

I have Table1 with data in it, Table1 is a large spreadsheet with many columns

| id | first name | last name | age | score | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | aa | zz | 5 | D | ... |
| P2 | dd | xx | 6 | A | ... |
| P3 | cc | yy | 7 | E | ... |

And I have a large empty Table2 with give column names:

| id | first name | school | age | score | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | ... |
|  |  |  |  |  | ... |
|  |  |  |  |  | ... |

some column names match with Table1.

How to fill Table2 using data in Table1 that automatically matching overlaped column names? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Do you have tables in a database or a spreadsheet?  Why is this tagged with both MySQL and Excel?

Comment: They're in Excel spreadsheet, I can connect to MySQL too. Just wonder if automatic matching column names is possible in either software?

Answer (score 0):

In excel you have option of connecting it to MySql db. Use option From Other Sources in Data menu to get connected to MySql and fetch the table structure. Now you can copy paste data and update the table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL contains views known as the *information schema* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html), which you can query to find the columns in a specific table.  So you can use it to find the columns that are the same in both tables.  You can use that information to construct a query that moves data between matching columns.  This will require you to construct the query in an environment that allows you to create and execute dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you Nielsen for pointing me to the right direction. Do you mind drop some commands likely for this I can start with, as I'm new to MySQL? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like `select a.column_name from (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='table_1') as a inner join (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='table_2') as b on a.column_name = b.column_name;` will get you a list of all column names in common.  Your table formats, environment, and requirements aren't described in detail, so that's all that's clearly relevant.  If you have trouble taking it further, you might post another question.